# Excel VBA updating links

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a VBA macro to update link paths in excel. I looked up some code online and tried to put it together, and am getting errors. I am wondering if i could get some direction here. Please note that i am not a programmer by profession, just trying to reduce some manual updating work.

Cheers!

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim bookname As String
Dim wbook As Workbook
Dim oldname As String
Dim newname As String

oldname = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\[Broadstreet.xlsx]"

newname = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\[Broadstreet2.xlsx]"

FolderPath = "C:\Users\XX\Documents1"


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With


For Each Workbook In FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
    bookname = Workbook.Name

    MsgBox (bookname)

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & bookname)

   ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink oldname1, newname1, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks


   wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome. You said that you are "getting errors". It would be helpful to describe or display the error. Provide as much information as possible so that it makes it easy for someone to assist you. You should read the help section of [mcve] and update your question with more information

Comment: probably remove the square brackets `[]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink#example

Answer (score 1):

## Workbooks in Folder Treatment

> - Loops through all Excel files (workbooks) in a folder, opens each    one, changes a link from one document to another, saves the changes and closes the workbook.

- `xlLinkTypeExcelLinks` is the **default** parameter of the `Type`
  argument of the `ChangeLink` method and can therefore be omitted.
- `.Close True` can be used in this way because `SaveChanges` is the
  **first** argument of the `Close` method.

### The Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Const strOld As String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\[Broadstreet.xlsx]"
  Const strNew As String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\[Broadstreet2.xlsx]"
  Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents1"
  Const strExt As String = "*.xls*"

  Dim strName As String

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
  End With

  On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

  strName = Dir(strPath & "\" & strExt)

  Do While strName <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strName)
      .ChangeLink strOld, strNew
      .Close True
    End With
    strName = Dir
  Loop

ProcedureExit:
  With Application
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

End Sub
```